# What's the difference between "stared at" and "stared off at?"

Tags: word-choice, sentence

What's the difference between these two sentences?

> Mary stared at the distance
>
> Mary stared off at/into the distance

Comment: jano, intersting, +1! However, for what is worth, I think that "stared at the distance" is not idiomatic English because "the distance" is not a thing that you can "stare at". In other words, "the distance" is an unidentified space or place. But it would be proper to say "Mary stared at the wall behind you" in wich "the wall" is a concrete thing with a fixed place in the space around. Please, consider also "Mary stared off *into* the distance."

Comment: @Carlo_R. Thanks! (You should turn this into an answer). By the way, why "into" is more appropriate than "at"? For the same reason you just mentioned?

Comment: jano, idiomatic English is diffucult and I'm not sure of being able to answer this question, but, as I see "into" in your case, it give a sense of perspective and largeness, also a sense of throughness, that "at" doesn't render.

Comment: @Carlo_R. OK, I think I understand. I think it's like when you say "He feel into the darkness."

Comment: It’s not really like when you say, “He feel[s] into the darkness”, because you don’t say that—it makes no sense. Or did you mean, “He fell into (the) darkness”? Apart from that, Carlo is right. You stare _at_ something that you can fix your eyes on; you stare (off) _into_ something that you cannot fix your eyes on (the distance, space, nothingness, the abyss, thin air, etc.).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Sorry, I meant "He fell into the darkness." OK, I see. I understand now. I think we should turn these comments into answers, ha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per comments from Carlo and Janus, normally we only *stare, look, peer, glare, etc. **at*** things we can actually *see*.

We don't normally think of *seeing* things like *distance, darkness, gloom, murk,* etc. These are really words for *the medium **through which** we [might possibly] see something*.

There's scope for a degree of uncertainty here though. Although we normally [stare **at** the horizon](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stared%20at%20the%20horizon,stared%20into%20the%20horizon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) (which can be "seen"), and [stare **into** the darkness](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stared%20into%20the%20darkness,stared%20at%20the%20darkness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) or [stare **into** the distance](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stared%20into%20the%20distance,stared%20at%20the%20distance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) (abstract things that can't be "seen" as such), in all cases the links show a few instances using the "wrong" preposition.

In some cases *(He looked **at/into** her eyes; She stared **at/into** the flames)*, both prepositions are possible (using ***into*** implies trying to discern something *within* or *beyond* the eyes/flames).

---

There's little difference between *stare **into** the distance* and *stare **off into** the distance*. Arguably, including ***off*** (less commonly, [***out, away***](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stared%20into%20the%20distance,stared%20off%20into%20the%20distance,stared%20out%20into%20the%20distance,stared%20away%20into%20the%20distance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)) emphasises that you're *not* looking at anything more relevant that might be nearby (such as a person who's talking to you). But it's a fine distinction.

Comment: To make your example pairs a bit more tangible:  her doctor might look **at** her eyes, but her lover would look **into** them; a scientist might stare **at** the flames, but a philosopher would stare **into** them.  Also, I'd say that you _stare **into** the distance_ when you're trying to make out something not yet visible - if you're a lookout, for example - and you _stare **off into** the distance_ when you're daydreaming.

Answer (score 0):

Prepositions help the reader or listener understand the relationship (the logical relationship, the spacial relationship or the temporal relationship between words or phrases.  Often as not that relationship is further clarified by the context of the rest of the sentence.  Consequently, their informative value may be so slight that the selection of the "right" preposition is purely idiomatic.  One stands "on line" to purchase a ticked to see a film in London, but he stands "in line" to purchase a ticket in the United States.  Similarly, if I spend the night "in Mary's house" there is a suggestion that Mary is not present and I am making sure her house is inhabited while she is away.  If I spend the night "at Mary's house" she, or at least her family, is there as well.  If I find myself sleeping "with Mary," then there some suggestion that Mary and I are sleeping in the same bed and may have had sexual congress.  When learning a 2nd language the subtle differences in the selection of prepositions are often the last things one learns.

Comment: -1 The OP asked what is the difference between stare *at* and stare *off at*. You are talking about something quite different. It's not a *bad* answer, but it's not *right* either. You can always edit your answer to make any necessary changes.